# Coffee-script installation failure

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install coffee-script on ubuntu 12.04. I am getting this error. I tried with npm (ver. 1.1.4) install command too, but it also failed.

```
  $ sudo coffeescript/bin/cake install

node.js:201

throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
```

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'existsSync' at cakefileDirectory (/home/gerceka/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:104:12)
>
> at Object.exports.run (/home/gerceka/coffeescript/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:51:19)
>
> at Object. (/home/gerceka/coffeescript/bin/cake:7:38)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:459:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)
>
> at Array.Module.runMain [as 0] (module.js:479:10)
>
> at EventEmitter.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)

I think I need this for genieacs installation. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo npm install -g coffee-script` you could alternately `git clone` the repo and manually adjust the `$PATH` in your `.bashrc` to include the directory. Those versions of everything are all quite old: ubuntu current LTS is 16.04, npm is now on 3.10, etc. I'd guess that you have a version incompatibility.

Comment: @JaredSmith Let's give credit where credit is do.  Please supply your advice as an answer, so that Gerçek AKÇA can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information. I upgraded my Ubuntu Version to 14.04. After that I had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I think npm does it for you when you do `npm run compile`.

Anyway, if you need a working instance, I wrote [a guide for GenieACS v1.0-stable](https://github.com/zaidka/genieacs/wiki/Installation-in-Ubuntu-14.04-Server,-64-bit). It's going to be outdated in some months, but for now is the latest stable option.

If you have these types of questions, better to post them in the [mailing list of GenieACS-Users](http://lists.genieacs.com/).